# Can dozen of mobx inject function affect performance?

Tags: reactjs, redux, wrapper, mobx

Using inject mapping can make components much more independent and encapsulated. But in this case, the codebase can be full of injects functions and hence, there will much more components in virtual DOM tree because each inject() is basically the wrapper component.

Does this lead to performance issues or the impact is so low that can be neglected?

Same can be applied to redux connect wrapper, i suppose

Answer (score 0):

I believe that impact is very low, basically negligible. It's virtual dom that we are talking about. Rendering to (changing) real dom is where all the performance bottlenecks come from.

Comment: yeah, but at the same time, there are dozen of recommendations to reduce the number of inline functions in render methods because of memory leaks. That is the similar issue cuz there will be more memory consumptions to render all of these injects/connects and map props there, creating new objects, arrays or other stuff